# (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided. (hosting a discord bot)

Tags: heroku

when ever I run my bot I get the error bellow
Ik the token is valid and it worked on glitch fine

my bot code: https://github.com/legouju/funtimesbottrytwo/tree/master
(srry if im bothering u guys, im new to heroku)

what the logs says:

2018-11-08T01:02:06.643169+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at _receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:220:12)
2018-11-08T01:02:06.643170+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:535:15)
2018-11-08T01:02:06.643172+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.finalize (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:206:20)
2018-11-08T01:02:06.643173+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
2018-11-08T01:02:06.643339+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
2018-11-08T01:02:06.644702+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2018-11-08T01:02:06.806551+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-11-08T01:09:10.724894+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2018-11-08T01:09:10.613680+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@0:Free worker@0:Free by user johnmo123jm@gmail.com
2018-11-08T01:09:12.333365+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@0:Free worker@1:Free by user johnmo123jm@gmail.com
2018-11-08T01:09:15.179891+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2018-11-08T01:09:15.924170+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897595+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897616+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.client.ws.connection.once.event (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientManager.js:48:41)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897618+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897620+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:182:13)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897621+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onClose (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897623+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897624+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897626+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at _receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:220:12)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897628+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:535:15)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897629+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.finalize (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:206:20)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897631+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897691+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
2018-11-08T01:09:17.897804+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2018-11-08T01:09:17.991004+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-11-08T01:09:17.993376+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-11-08T01:09:17.957224+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-11-08T01:09:20.088995+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2018-11-08T01:09:20.790067+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-11-08T01:09:23.458015+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386529+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386549+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.client.ws.connection.once.event (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientManager.js:48:41)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386550+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386552+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:182:13)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386553+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onClose (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386554+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386555+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386556+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at _receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:220:12)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386557+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:535:15)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386558+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.finalize (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:206:20)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386560+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386689+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
2018-11-08T01:09:23.386844+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2018-11-08T01:09:23.570331+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error message is trying to tell you the following:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error 
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

This is an error to do with your code. Also there is another error you should take a look at:

```
08T01:09:17.897595+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were 
provided. 2018-11-08T01:09:17.897616+00:00 app[worker.1]: at 
WebSocketConnection.client.ws.connection.once.event
```

Seems like there were incorrect credentials, review your code and see if your db authorizations are correct ect

Comment: So, I think it might be wise if you update your question with your code, what you are trying to achieve, and some general knowledge about your problem. It would really help others who wish to assist you with your problem.